# JPA: export query result to CSV format

Tags: java, jpa, csv, entity, opencsv

Which is the best way to export a JPA query result in a CSV format?
I tried opencsv but it wants a java.sql.ResultSet object and I don't understand how to create it. I tried the following code

```
public ResultSet getAllUsersMap() {
    String query = "SELECT p from Participant p ORDER BY p.lastName";
    ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
    return rs;
}
```

but I receive the exception *java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Vector cannot be cast to java.sql.ResultSet*

Answer (score 0):

JPA is an ORM framework spec. It's not directly related to creating CSV files.  The error is just saying that you are casting the return value of method `getResultList()` to the wrong type.

Using opencsv, something like this should work:

```
String query = "SELECT p from Participant p ORDER BY p.lastName";
List resultList = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();

BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("result.csv"));
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(out);
for (Object item : resultList) {
    String line = formatParticipantToLine(item) // method to format properties of Participant with comma's
    writer.writeNext(item);
}
writer.close();
```

UPDATE:
You can also use http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/bean/BeanToCsv.html
with `Participant` your bean of course.

Comment: @k-c thanks for your answer. Only to understand, if I've to write a method to create a line with all properties of each item separated by commas, why I've to use opencsv? I thought that opencsv did it automatically. Isn't it?

Comment: At the end I've to create a String[] object to use CSVWriter.

Comment: Read the API of opencsv, you can use for example : http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#javabean-integration

Comment: I read about that, but I don't understand well what means. I'll check the opencsv test case to learn more about it. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if I understand well, but reading the test cases, seems that you can read a csv file and bind the content to entity properties. Not in the other way.

Comment: There is not only a `CsvToBean` class, but also a `BeanToCsv` class. See link in my updated response.

Comment: Ok, I'll check. Thanks.

Comment: The API documentation is referred to a 2.4 version that I'm unable to find. The latest version released is the 2.3 that hasn't the BeanToCsv class.  For the moment I solved mixing your code with a method that create a String[] object from the entity properties.

Comment: Not in the .gz file indeed, but I found it in the trunk: http://sourceforge.net/p/opencsv/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/bean/  You will have to check the trunk in and build opencsv yourself. I don't know if it's bugfree ...

Comment: Thanks again. I'll check.